# Best JS framework can be used with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I'm a new user in SharePoint, I wanna create forms, session, CRUD operations, send messages via Skype API.

I'm confused which JS framework I have to use with SharePoint in client-side and why?

Angular JS, Vue JS, Knockout JS, React JS.. Or other JS framework?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with learning SharePoint first

You can do all development without using any Framework, we have done so for the past 15 years

A Framework is a tool which makes **a** task easier; which tool to use depends on the Task

- Since you don't know SharePoint,
- you don't know which Tasks you have to do
- you can not select a tool/framework

PS. it is VueJS, not ViewJS